# Pytorch Assigning fixed parameter to the model

Tags: parameters, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am only interest in the feature map after 2 convolution layers with specific weights.

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        )
        with torch.no_grad():
            weights1 = torch.tensor([[0.2390, 0.1593], [0.5377, 0]])
            self.layer1.weight = nn.Parameter(weights1, requires_grad=False)

        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=1, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
        )
        with torch.no_grad():
            weights2 = torch.tensor([[-0.2390, -0.3585], [-0.5377, 0.2390]])
            self.layer2.weight = nn.Parameter(weights2, requires_grad=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        x = self.layer2(x)
        return x
```

Due to the limitation of real sensor implementation, I have to use fixed weights as above.
Problem is that the output is not constant.

```
>>>list(model.parameters())
[Parameter containing:
tensor([[0.2390, 0.1593],
        [0.5377, 0.0000]]), Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[-0.2701,  0.1602],
          [-0.0056, -0.0924]]]], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.2390, -0.3585],
        [-0.5377,  0.2390]]), Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[-0.0287,  0.2864],
          [ 0.3319, -0.3913]]]], requires_grad=True)]
```

Above is the result of model's parameter and you can see there are other parameters.

Do you know how to fix the paramteres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not accessing the `weight` property on the incorrect object: `self.layer1` and `self.layer2` are not `nn.Conv2d` instances, they are `nn.Sequential` layers. Doing so you are essentially registering two new tensors (the fixed ones) to your module, added the two tensor parameters instantiated by the `nn.Conv2d` layers.

You should assign the fixed parameters to `self.layer1[0]` and (`self.layer2[0]` respectively):

```
self.layer1[0].weight = nn.Parameter(weights1, requires_grad=False)
# and
self.layer2[0].weight = nn.Parameter(weights2, requires_grad=False)
```

Then `.parameters()` will generate two tensor parameters:

```
>>> list
[Parameter containing:
 tensor([[0.2390, 0.1593],
         [0.5377, 0.0000]]), Parameter containing:
 tensor([[-0.2390, -0.3585],
         [-0.5377,  0.2390]])]
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you very much.